# SSRS report parameter.label showing parameter.value

Tags: ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a SSRS report, in my report I have a dataset which has an ID and NAME field, then I created a parameter and set its value to ID from dataset and Label to NAME of dataset. I can see the label when I preview report and select it, but I am also showing the selected parameter on report for this I am using expression :

> =Parameters!P_TargetBrand.Label

But when report runs it is showing parameter VALUE instead of Label.

My SQL version is :

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: I have the same environment (MS SQL 2008R2 SP1) but can't reproduce this. Is there some additional information?

Comment: Im am using visual studio 2010 to develop SSRS report, In my Visual Studio I have installed Development Tools For MS AX 2012, this is SSRS report for AX 2012.

Comment: I think its a bug. I am also having a parameter kpi_id with value & label but when I use parameter.label in my chart title, it shows me value not label. Its single value parameter.

Answer (score 31):

Case when your parameter is Single Value :

```
=Parameters!<ParameterName>.Label
```

Case when your parameter is Multi Values :

```
=Parameters!<ParameterName>.Label(0)
```

OR

```
=Join(Parameters!<MultivalueParameterName>.Label,", ")
```

[For Additional information try here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: H @GilPeretz It's not working for me. I think its a bug. I am also having a parameter kpi_id with value & label but when I use parameter.label in my chart title, it shows me value not label. Its single value parameter.

Comment: =Parameters!<ParameterName>.Label(0) this works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem and as far as I can tell it is a <s>bug</s> unsupported feature.

On this page - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731894.aspx

## They have two issues that are related to our problem:

#### "The Label reference does not display properly. The Value property is set to the Parameters!MyParm.Value parameter."

Addtl. Info: "The parameter must be explicitly bound to data using a dataset in the Visual Studio Tools for Microsoft Dynamics AX report model."

and

#### "The parameter is explicitly bound to datasets with two columns, label and value. The value displays properly. The Label reference displays properly everywhere except in the client."

Addtl. Info: "The report viewer control does not support the ability to specify report parameter labels, only values."

---

In my case we're not using a bound dataset.  Just our own backend and adding the parameter values to the reporting view object. So we're SOL.  Really lame that we have to get a label/value pair.  Then hit the database again to get the label for the selected value since we don't have direct access to the label.

I would love to be proven wrong.